# How to run unix enq command in java program

Tags: java, unix

Here is the unix command for adding a file to the queue.

```
enq -P QueueName:PrinterName FileName
```

Is it possible to run the above command using java.

Comment: Look at the "Process" class

Comment: can u give me some more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

```
ProcessBuilder builder = 
           new ProcessBuilder("enq", "-P", "QueueName", "FileName");
Process process = builder.start();
InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
}
```

See: [enq syntax](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds2/enq.htm)

Comment: enq –P {print queue}  file

Comment: above command can be a unix command?if yes then print queue and file name is enough for above command,don't want printer name?

Answer (score 0):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"enq", "-P", "QueueName:PrinterName FileName"});
```

Comment: That's the old way. ProcessBuilder is the way to go now (and has been for several years)